# Mount / with atime

Tags: mount, fstab

I'm trying to get my root partition to mount with the `atime` option on boot. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

I've modified my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
UUID=334a0fe1-2636-4ee6-93b5-8748c5313c79 / ext4 atime,errors=remount-ro 0
```

...but that has no effect:

```
$ mount | head -n1
# => /dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```

What is it that I need to do, please?

Comment: As far as I know, `atime`mostly is the default option, so you don't need to define that. It's just used with mount operations to override default `noatime`option.

Comment: @ridgy : I believe that since 2007, `relatime` has been the default. `man mount` says of `relatime`: Since  Linux 2.6.30, the kernel defaults to the behavior provided by this option (unless noatime was specified),  and  the  strictatime  option  is  required to obtain  traditional  semantics.

Comment: Anyway, my real goal is to find when `/bin/login` was last called. It does not appear to show the time when I last logged in to my system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### From Fstab pages:

#### atime options:

The `atime` options below can impact drive performance.

1. The `atime` option means use kernel default value. As of kernel 2.3 or so, the kernel default is `relatime`. This option is not needed if `defaults` or `relatime` are specified.
2. The `strictatime` option updates the access time of the files every time they are accessed. This is more purposeful when Linux is used for
   servers; it does not have much value for desktop use. The drawback
   about the `strictatime` option is that even reading a file from the
   page cache (reading from memory instead of the drive) will still
   result in a write!
3. The `noatime` option fully disables writing file access times to the drive every time you read a file. This works well for almost all
   applications, except for those that need to know if a file has been
   read since the last time it was modified. The write time information
   to a file will continue to be updated anytime the file is written to
   with this option enabled.
4. The `nodiratime` option disables the writing of file access times only for directories while other files still get access times written.
   Note: `noatime` implies `nodiratime`. You do not need to specify both.
5. The `relatime` option is currently the kernel default value. It updates the access time only if the previous access time was earlier
   than the current modify or change time. In addition, since Linux
   2.6.30, the access time is always updated if the previous access time was more than 24 hours old. This option is used when the `defaults`
   option or `atime` option are not specified.
6. Kernel 4.0 and newer, the `lazytime` option reduces writes to disk by maintaining changes to inode timestamps (access, modification and
   creation times) only in memory. The on-disk timestamps are updated
   only when either:
   a) the file inode needs to be updated for some change unrelated to file timestamps,
   b) a sync to disk occurs,
   c) an undeleted inode is evicted from memory or
   d) if more than 24 hours passed since the the last time the in-memory copy was written to disk.

#### Thus you need:

```
UUID=334a0fe1-2636-4ee6-93b5-8748c5313c79 / ext4 strictatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

If you have kernel 4.0 or newer, I would recommend adding 'lazytime` to increase performance and reduce drive writes:

```
UUID=334a0fe1-2636-4ee6-93b5-8748c5313c79 / ext4 strictatime,lazytime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

#### Sources:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29#Solutions